# Why not have all variables be a constexpr?

Tags: c++

sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but I dont have much experience with C++ programming and im trying to learn as much as a I can about its syntax. I came across the specifier constexpr and was wondering that if it allows you to save time at runtime, why not declare all your variables with it?

Comment: Because not every variable is a compile time constant?

Comment: Because then your application would never give a different result. If the entire behaviour is determinable at compile-time, you effectively don't have to bother with runtime.

Comment: Because variables are typically, well, variable at run-time.

Comment: If the initializer of your variable is not compile-time constant, then this variable cannot be declared with `constexpr` specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all not all variables can be made `constexpr`. For example

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
```

Obviously `x` cannot be `constexpr`. The value it will have after it has been read from input is not a compile-time constant.

Second, `constexpr` is part of the contract of a variable or function. By marking it `constexpr`, you allow other code to use it in a context that requires a constant expression. That means even if it might be possible to declare it `constexpr` now, you should not do so if you are planning on potentially changing the code so that it will not be `constexpr` later. If you were to mark it `constexpr` now, other code might come to rely on this property, and that code will stop compiling when `constexpr` is removed in a future version of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `constexpr` on a variable if the variable's initialization is a constant expression, meaning that its value is fully determined at compile-time. This is not the case for most variables which generally depend on user input.

`constexpr` also implies `const`. So you can never change a variable that is marked `constexpr`. Again, most variables are not supposed to be constant like that.

If you have a variable that is initialized with a compile-time constant and its value is supposed to never change, then yes, you should generally mark it `constexpr`.